# How to download media item from media library in sitecore?

Tags: media-library

I tried to download a media item from media library to my local storage using the Item ID. But it downloaded only in cache storage. I want to download it in downloads folder.

```
public void downloadform(string fileid)
{
    var mediaItem =Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(new ID(fileid));
    var media = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaItem);

    //Get Media Stream in buffer
    var mediaStream = media.GetStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)mediaStream.Length];
    mediaStream.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)mediaStream.Length);

    //Send response to browser
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString());
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + mediaItem.Name + ".pdf");
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Do want to download just a few items from Sitecore content editor or want to know some programmatical way for this?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat i want to download just a few items. Need some programmatical way too

Comment: Does this help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340195/how-to-download-sitecore-images?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code the download media into your local folder.

```
 var mediaItem = Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(new ID("{04DAD0FD-DB66-4070-881F-17264CA257E1}"));
    var media = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaItem);

    var stream = media.GetStream();

    using (var targetStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine("D:/Go", mediaItem.Name + ".jpeg")))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(targetStream);
        targetStream.Flush();
    }
```

Modify the code the get the child items and create the loop and set this logic into that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Send-File command. When executed on a media library item, it allows you to download the associated blob stored in that item.

```
Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "/sitecore/media library/" | Send-File
```

You can pass -NoDialog to it so the user is not prompted each time.

So for multiple files you can do:

```
Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "/sitecore/media library/Images/" | Send-File -NoDialog
```

Hope this helps.